# WL.Utils in Worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

1. I have seen a new feature in worklight `WL.utils.`(etc).
2. What are the utils function available and where can i find the information regarding `WL.Utils` since there is no information in the [IBM InfoCenter](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.help.doc%2Fwl_home.html)?
3. why are they used in worklight ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WL.Utlis` is not new. It is a set of APIs that are used internally in Worklight's client-side  JavaScript framework.

You should refrain from using any methods in it, as they may change without notice and break your application and support will not be provided.

In fact, you should not use them at all.
We will work on masking them from being available. Thanks for bringing this to our attention.